# Passwordless SSH not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have set up passwordless ssh authentication (via authorized_keys) numerous times successfully and with ease, usually on servers that did not have any custom ssh-related configuration changes prior to that.

Now I need to set it up on a CentOS server where another person previously disabled this feature due to "security concerns" expressed by an ill-informed manager. That person is no longer available and I cannot figure out how to make this work.

I have this in the sshd_config:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
UsePAM yes
```

There are other settings, but I thought they did not make a difference. Any suggestions what I should check to make this work?

Comment: Permissions on `authorized_keys` and `.ssh`? try connecting with `-vv` and post the results.

Comment: What error message are you seeing ? Can you add the ouput of `ssh -vvv ...` to you question?

Comment: It was the permissions on authorized_keys, now I almost feel stupid ;). But not as stupid as I would have been if I kept torturing the sshd config to try to get it to work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common reason I have seen is permissions to ~/.ssh/authorized keys is too permissive.  The authorized keys file must have read/write ONLY for the owner (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`).  The directory itself can also not allow any writes (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`)

Comment: chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized keys I think

Comment: You are correct...bad place to typo :)

Comment: I cannot believe I got fooled by this simple thing! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can actually comment out `AuthorizedKeysFile`, as it's the default.

What's the server logging when failing currently? Have you checked permissions on `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` and/or disabled `StrictModes`?

Increase the `LogLevel` if necessary and/or run `sshd` in detached mode.

Answer (score 2):

Quick-and-dirty solution: copy /etc/ssh/sshd_config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config from a server where it works.

You could also strip all comments from the files on working and non-working server (e.g. run `egrep -v '^#' /etc/ssh/sshd_config | sort | uniq` and compare results on both servers.

Also look at the directory and file permissions, as Alex suggested.

Comment: vote up for the very handy grep command

Comment: ssh_config controls the client-side of ssh, copying it to the server you want to connect to is not useful.

Comment: Right, there's no point copying client's config to the server side.